# Function to return a string legal for a range name

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote an Excel VBA function that will take a string argument and return a string that is legal for naming a range.  Upon looking through this, if you're wondering what I've been smoking, I should add a disclaimer that I'm new to VBA and I have not yet come across a less restrictive way to obtain this functionality.  And, of course, please feel welcome to modify and use it for your own purposes.

```vb
Function Namify(inputName As String) As String
'Takes a string argument and returns a modified string suitable for use as a name

    'Create a string to be modified and returned
    Dim workingName As String
    workingName = inputName

    'Create a string array containing all the valid characters in an Excel name
    Dim validchars() As Variant
    validchars = Array("_", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", _
        "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", _
        "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", _
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", _
        "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z")

    'Iterate through each character of the string argument and replace that character
    'with an underscore if it's an illegal character.
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(inputName)

        'Is the character illegal? If so replace it in workingName
        If IsError(Application.Match(Mid(inputName, i, 1), validchars, 0)) Then
            workingName = Replace(workingName, Mid(inputName, i, 1), "_")
        End If

    Next i

    'Detect whether the first character in workingName is a number.
    Dim numbers() As Variant
    numbers = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0")

    If Not IsError(Application.Match(Mid(workingName, 1, 1), numbers, 0)) Then
        workingName = "_" & workingName
    End If

    'return the string that is now legal to use as a name.
    Namify = workingName

End Function
```

**How I use it:**

I have a macro that gets a text name from the user, instantiates a new object, and displays the user-input name in a cell followed by the object's property values in cells to the right. Then the sub calls Namify (user-selected name) to create a prefix for assigning a unique name to all these cells so their values can be updated with changes to the object's properties. The prefix itself is stored as a property of the object for later retrieval.

**Some potential problems for this function** (feel free to add to this list by editing or asking me to add in a comment):

- It could return a name that is also a valid cell address.
- It would return the same string from arguments with different illegal characters in the same position. (Example arguments: "User;Name", "User=Name")
- It does not return all possible arrangements of valid characters.
- It would return any of the one-character strings "C", "c", "R", "r"
- There is no limit on the length of the returned string

**What I'd like to know:**

- Is this a reasonable approach for allowing the user to create whatever name they like and then using a version of that name to name objects and ranges?
- What ideas do you have to make this function more rigorous or more useful?

**Disclaimer:** I accepted [Mat's Mug](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23788/mats-mug)'s answer because it worked well for me. [AlexR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/54095/alexr)'s [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/119102/96671) does appear to be the ideal way to handle this, however VB regular expressions aren't natively supported on my version of Excel (for Mac 2011). Please have a look at his answer if you're interested in optimizing something like my function for yourself.

**Follow Up:** With some great answers on the board, I revised this function and posted it in a [follow up question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/119307/function-to-return-a-legal-name-for-an-excel-range-follow-up).  Please have a look at it before posting additional answers here.

Comment: I'm gonna leave this link to [the doc describing named range syntax rules](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64#bmsyntax_rules_for_names) here for the convenience of reviewers.

Comment: Thanks RubberDuck, I referred to a less descriptive set of rules when I wrote it, but I can see now that I have some more problems to add to the list.

Comment: You're welcome @JeremyCaron. I think you'll get some good advice here. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice code, I like what you've been smoking. An alternative (better?) name for the function could have been `Legalize`, too.

You could easily modify it to optionaly verify existing names (e.g. `Optional ByVal verify As Boolean = False`), and append a digit (or increment an existing one?) to the return value if `verify` is `True` and the resulting name already exists in `ActiveWorkbook.Names`.

Nitpick: `inputName` is implicitly passed `ByRef`, and should be passed `ByVal` to clearly say "I'm not modifying my input here" - with a `ByRef` parameter if your function reassigns the parameter, the caller gets to see the new value (and that would be... yuck!).

The function is also implicitly `Public`, which is much less of an issue, but still for readability's sake I like to see things explicit - especially since VBA's defaults (`ByRef`/`Public`) are pretty much upside down compared to most languages.

That said, I don't like the [ab]use of worksheet functions in VBA code. For example, this:

> ```
> 'Is the character illegal? If so replace it in workingName
> If IsError(Application.Match(Mid(inputName, i, 1), validchars, 0)) Then
> ```

Should be using the `InStr` VBA function instead of `Application.Match` and `IsError`.

Then again this:

> ```
> 'Detect whether the first character in workingName is a number.
> Dim numbers() As Variant
> numbers = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0")
>
> If Not IsError(Application.Match(Mid(workingName, 1, 1), numbers, 0)) Then
> ```

Could be rewritten like this:

```
If Not IsNumeric(Left(workingName,1)) Then
```

---

You should also make sure that the resulting string is less than 255 characters, and... I think I'd replace invalid characters with `vbNullString` instead of an underscore.

The `validChars` array doesn't need to distinguish upper and lower case characters, so long as you specify `vbTextCompare` (default is `vbBinaryCompare`, which is indeed case-sensitive) when you use `InStr` to determine if a character is legal - a helper function like this can be tremendously helpful for this:

```
Public Function ContainsAny(ByVal string_source As String, ByVal caseSensitive As Boolean, ParamArray find_strings() As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim find As String, i As Integer, found As Boolean

    For i = LBound(find_strings) To UBound(find_strings)

        find = CStr(find_strings(i))
        found = Contains(string_source, find, caseSensitive)

        If found Then Exit For
    Next

    ContainsAny = found

End Function
```

With this function, you don't even need to declare the array anymore - you could just inline the valid characters into the call, like this:

```
If Not ContainsAny(Mid(inputName,i,1), False, "_", _
    "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", _
    "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", _
    "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z") _
Then
    'character is illegal
End If
```

<sub>I wonder if there's a noticeable difference in performance between this approach and your possibly better-performing `Match` approach.</sub>

Comment: No regex or pattern matching? Man. Now I've got to write a review.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I was not expecting to get a good thorough answer THAT quickly. Clearly I should be smoking your stuff.  I'll implement whichever changes I can handle and post the updated code with a description of the changes as an answer.

Comment: @JeremyCaron or you could post the updated code as a follow-up question if you want more feedback on it then - see [this post](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765/23788) on meta for important information on following-up.

Answer (score 5):

Using a `VBScript.RegExp` will greatly help clean your algorithm:

```
Static reg As Object
If reg Is Nothing Then
    Set reg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    reg.Pattern = "(?:^(?=\d)|\W)" 'A Digit at the start or any illegal character
    reg.Global = True 'Replace all matches
End If
Namify = reg.Replace(inputName, "_")
```

This does the same as your entire function. Read more about RegExps [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx)

If you additionally write a function `ContainsName(name As String) As Boolean` wich traverses `ActiveWorkbook.Names` and returns `True` if `name` is a valid name, you can add an additional feature to generate a valid *new* name as Mat suggests:

```
Static trailingNum As Object
Dim number As String
If trailingNum Is Nothing Then
    Set trailingNumm = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    trailingNum.Pattern = "\d*$"
End If
While ContainsName(Namify)
    number = trailingNum.Execute(Namify)(0).Value
    If Len(number) = 0 Then number = "0"
    Namify = trailingNum.Replace(Namify, CStr(CInt(number) + 1))
End While
```

Comment: Ah! I was hoping for someone to come along and mention regular expressions!

Comment: Taking a look at the specs for character classes I found the legal characters are precisely `\w`, so we can even use `\W` for the illegal ones.

Comment: I'm using Excel for Mac 2011 and it looks like `VBScript.RegExp` isn't natively supported on Macs (...regret).  I'm seeing some discussion around writing the regular expression in Perl and handling the I/O with [this method](http://illcode.org/post/14265165805/writing-mac-compatible-file-io-code-in-vba). I'll look into it, but I have a sinking feeling I'd be getting way over my head with this.  Thank you for the suggestion though.  This does seem to be the ideal way to do it.

Comment: @JeremyCaron That's too bad. There is a SO question on RegEx for Excel on Mac, maybe this can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344932/regex-with-vba-excel-at-mac